# MasterDetailPage navigate only first click

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have a MasterDetailPage implemented:

```
public MasterPage()
{menuList = new List<Models.MasterPageItem>();
var index= new Models.MasterPageItem() { Title = "index", Icon =index.png, TargetType = typeof(Index.Index) };
var client= new Models.MasterPageItem() { Title = "Clients", Icon =client.png, TargetType = typeof(Login.Client) };
menuList.Add(index);
menuList.Add(client);
navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;
Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Dashboard)));
 }
private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e){
Type page = item.TargetType;
Detail.Navigation.PushAsync((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
IsPresented = false;
 }
```

the problem is , if i click on client, the navigation works, but if i press back it works also , the problem when i click again on client , dosent work , i must navigate on index or another item , and the click on client , i can't navigate twice on same item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the name implies, `SelectedItemChanged` only fires on **changes**.  So if you tap the same option twice in a row, it only fires once.  The workaround is to set

```
navigationDrawerList.SelectedtedItem = null;
```

in the event handler before you havigate

Comment: thanks for ur quick answer , the event(OnMenuItemSelected) dosent called on second click ,else where i can add SelectedItem=null ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I told you.  Set it to null the **first** time

Comment: e.SelectedItem = null; ? here a problem ! (cannot be assigned )

Comment: `navigationDrawerList.SelectedItem = null;`